# Is there anyway in c++ to make a function of a class who's objects each do something different for that function?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

Just some background:

I am making a monopoly game and now I have to implement the actions of each space such as GO, properties (upgrading), chance, community chest, jail, etc.

I've considered making a different class for each space (but obviously that would be very time consuming). I believe there is also a way do to it with inheritance and pure virtual functions. Any way you guys can think that would make this a simpler process?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very general, in programming there are many ways of getting the job done. You must be more specific.

Comment: sounds like strategy pattern

Comment: One of the simplest ways is to have a data member in the class that specifies which type of space it is, then have the function `switch` on that data member to the appropriate action.  Something like `enum Space { Go, Property, Chance, Community_Chest, Jail }; Space space_;` then `switch (space_) { case Go: ... break; ... }`

Comment: @40two Sorry you're completely right. Basically I want to see if there is a way I can just call something like Space[number].action(...) and have it automatically know which function to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can make a function do different things given an object:

1. Differentiate the behavior based on the data of the object.

   You could capture the differences in the various spaces using data.

   ```
   enum SpaceType
   {
     GO, CHANCE, COMMUNITY_CHEST,  // etc...
   };

   class Space
   {
     public:

       void foo()
       {
           switch (spaceType)
           {
             case GO:
               // DO stuff for GO
               break;
             case CHANCE:
               // DO stuff for CHANCE
               break;
             // etc..
           }
       }
     private:
       SpaceType spaceType;
   }
   ```
2. Differentiate the behavior based on the type of an object.

   ```
   class Space
   {
      public:
        virtual void foo() = 0;
   };

   class GoSpace : public Space
   {
      public:
        virtual void foo()
        {
          // Do stuff for GO
        }
   };

   class ChanceSpace : public Space
   {
      public:
        virtual void foo()
        {
          // Do stuff for CHANCE
        }
   };

   // Similarly for other classes.
   ```

Pick your method. Personally, I would pick the second method because the logic for each different type is put into their own functions, without the complications of what other types do.

Comment: Best practice is to reserve uppercase identifiers for macros (other than single letters possibly followed by numbers which are often used for template parameters, albeit at some risk)... code is then less likely to break if you include some header that happens to define a similar macro.

Answer (score 1):

There are only a few different types of spaces:

- properties
- railroads
- chance / community chest
- utilities
- other single ones like go, jail, parking, tax

For example you could have a `Property` class where each instance of the class has a different name/colour/price. You wouldn't have to make 22 different classes, just have 22 instances of the same class with different names.

Note that having class instances that represent spaces you can land on is only one way to implement a game like that. I'm pretty sure I wouldn't choose that option.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I figured I can do that but I wanted to see if there is a better system where it would see what space a certain player is at. Then i would use their space and put it in the Space Class' action function then it would know what action to do.

Something like: Space.action(Player[i].getSpace);

If I am understanding you correctly I would have to use a bunch of if else statements to get you strategy working?


Sorry for the lack of code. I have to be cautious in case other classmates see this.